# Opera Portable puts a blue Downloads folder in my User's Favorites folder when the browser starts up

Tags: windows, opera, portable-apps

I just installed Opera Portable 12.16 on my flash drive from PortableApps.com.

When I start it up, a blue Downloads folder is created in my User's Favorites folder.

I have set up the Downloads path in Opera's Preferences for my User's Downloads folder as follows:

```
C:\Users\UserName\Downloads
```

---

The blue Downloads folder inside the Favorites folder is exactly the same as the "real" one just above the Favorites folder.

If I close Opera, delete the Downloads folder inside the Favorites folder, then reopen Opera, the Downloads folder is created again inside the Favorites folder. The create date/time for the Downloads folder inside the Favorites folder is when I opened Opera.

When I download something from the Internet, Opera tries to download it to my Documents folder. So, it is ignoring the path I set up and the new Downloads folder it created.

I am running Vista Home Premium.

---

I read on the Opera website forum that there is an option for installing a portable version from that website. It is version 16.0.1196.80. I tried installing and running that from my flash drive. I got the same results: The Downloads folder is created when I run that portable version.

---

Ha! I am glad you insisted on getting a screenshot. I found something else. In addition to the new blue Downloads folder inside the Favorites folder, there is also a new blue Downloads folder being created by Opera above the Favorites folder. (I marked all the blue Downloads folders with orange arrows in a paint program.) ([Original screenshot](http://imgur.com/delete/QF44hKHUuBNidmq))

[image: Screenshot]

The first (from the top) Downloads folder's Location is:
C:\Users\UserName\Favorites\Downloads
This is not correct.

When I delete the Downloads folder inside the Favorites folder, press F5 to refresh, this folder outside the Favorites folder disappears.

The second Downloads folder Properties does not have a Location tab. The Location field on the General tab shows:
C:\Users\UserName

The Downloads folder inside the Favorites folder has a Location of:
C:\Users\UserName\Favorites\Downloads

I should add that I tried adding a Downloads folder on my flash drive and then pointing the Downloads path in Opera to that folder on my flash drive. That did not help. I still get the extra blue Download folders on my hard drive.
G:\Opera_Portable\Downloads

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of that blue folder? Add the link to your question. Also, what OS do you use?

Comment: @nixda - The operating system is going to be Windows.  Since this problem would be on any version its not that important to know the specific version of Windows.

Comment: You can upload it to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) and add the link in your post.

Comment: Screenshot: See above at the end of the initial posted text.

Comment: Could you specify the "real"-locations of all those "downloads" folders? (Should be under Right-click and "Properties") I expect they all point to the same folder but these are "shortcuts" in the left-pane and not actually created folders. (I tried the portable version in Windows 7 Ultimate and had no problems with this)

Comment: I am running Vista Home Premium.                                     See text added after the screenshot above for locations.

Comment: Do you have any skin modifications tried in the past in your Windows Vista?

Comment: No. I have never used a skin. (I went and looked up what that was.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wow**, for a portable App, Opera seems to be doing **a lot** of poking around my system.
It even scans my dropbox-folder.

@Ken, could you do a registry search for `Favorites\Downloads` and `\Downloads` to see if you have the `Favorites\Downloads` somewhere in your registry? That could be the reason why Opera thinks it needs to create it?

For example, look in:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders

I have a key there named `{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}` pointing to  `%USERPROFILE%\Downloads`.

I changed the value to `%USERPROFILE%\Test\Downloads` (as a test) and Opera Portable created this `Test` directory (because it didn't exist) in `C:\Users\Username`. If you have the value `%USERPROFILE%\Favorites\Downloads` that's the problem and you'll need to change it. Of course Opera shouldn't **touch** the files on your harddrive in Portable mode, but it does.

Comment: I just want to add/clarify for others, that this Registry key is [not created by Opera](http://superuser.com/questions/267626/accidentally-deleted-the-downloads-folder-a-windows-special-folder-how-to-re). Windows uses this key to [know where your official downloads location is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882665.aspx)

Comment: Rik: I checked my registry in the location that you suggested. I did not have a Downloads folder listed. I did have a branch with a name of numbers like yours. The path was Favorites\Downloads. I changed it to just \Downloads and renamed it to Downloads. Thanks. I won't mess with Opera anymore. I am trying Chrome portable. I do appreciate your answer.  Ken  --  p.s. I am able to edit your answer here on superuser.com. Is that correct?

Comment: You shouldn't rename it to Downloads. The `{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}` as a special meaning (meaning Downloads). Maybe Windows will re-create it on its own but then it will also point to the correct location. (The renamed key Download will now not be used by Windows) p.s. With a reputation of 8 you could only edit your question. You shouldn't be able to edit an answer.

Comment: That's not good. I changed the name back. Hope it's OK. (Not a good thing to say when you are dealing with computers, I know.) When I download something from the Internet, it is going into the Downloads folder like it did before.

Comment: Yep. If you changed the name back and the download-location is ok, everything is fine.