# Messed up my Downloads folder. How to get it back?

Tags: windows-7, user-folders

I've changed my Downloads folder location to D:\Test\Downloads. 
Then I accidentally set the Desktop folder to D:\Test.

After getting it back to C:\Users\MyName\Desktop, the D:\Test\Downloads is not marked as a user folder anymore, meaning that at properties, the Location option is not more available.

Trying to get it back, I've created a folder named Downloads at C:\Users\MyName\Downloads, but it also does not have the Location option.

When I run (Windows+R) `shell:Downloads`, windows cannot find it.

```
So, how can I get back the Downloads folder?
```

OS: Windows 7 x64 Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to point the Downloads library link back to `D:\Test\Downloads`.

You can do that through `Right Click > Properties` then selecting the `Location` tab.

- `Restore` - This will set the path back to default, as you see in the screenshot.
- `Move...` - This opens a window that will let you choose a new location for the downloads directory.
- `Find Target...` - This will open the directory where the currently set `Downloads` folder resides. In the example below:  `C:\Users\Michael\`

[image: Download Properties]

Note: You can only get to the "correct" `Downloads` properties by entering from the \Users\Username\ folder directly. See the screenshot below:

[image: Download Properties 2]

If the above method doesn't work or the Location tab is **completely** gone, and you're not just looking in the wrong place. You may need to reset the Download folders registry link.

There are two locations that will need to be reset:

[image: HKCU > Shell Folders]

and

[image: HKCU > User Shell Folders]

Comment: As I said, the Location tab is gone. This is the problem. I can't find it, actually, I think it does not exists anymore, since "shell:Downloads" results in error. I need to reset it, but I don't know how/where. :(

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include a screenshot of which icon to enter properties from. I can't see if for some reason, hopefully you can.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the solution, I found it at: http://superuser.com/questions/267626/accidentally-deleted-the-downloads-folder-a-windows-special-folder-how-to-re

Comment: Next time, mention that you deleted the folder. ;)

Comment: I will say that @MichaelFrank did give an accurate answer, although there is an alternative when the tabs are not available, which it the answer you found.

Comment: I didn't, but you didn't understand that the Location tab was gone.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFrank for the very detailed answer. Unfortunately I can't mark it as answer since it is not the correct one. Also, I don't know how should I proceed in this case, when the answer is inside a similar question. Any moderator can help? :)

Comment: I'll add a couple screenshots to show the registry edit method as well. That way, it'll be a more complete answer for people with this problem in the future.